# Missing Cast Icon

Tags: google-cast

After setting up and running the "cast-android-sample" on my Nexus 7,
the app appears.

I recognize the 2 prompts:

- TAP to Select Media -> this works, I can select something, ex. "Tears of Steel"
- Tap Cast Icon to Select Cast Device -> but there is no cast icon anywhere.

The top pane of the app shows my app-id: db615adb-1e98-4559-8649-282f761d8721_1

On this Nexus 7 I concurrently run the Chromecast app, and YouTube, which 
let's me cast videos to the Chromecast attached to my TV.

Where is the Cast Icon ?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top right corner. The icon is white, so if you changed the action bar style to light or white, then you won't see it.
It also might not appear if there is some issue with your app id.

Comment: Thanks for your help: there is nothing in the top right corner.

Comment: In Eclipse, for file strings.xml it complains that I should replace the "-" in the ID: could that be the problem ?

Comment: No, that should be fine.

Comment: AcitivityManager Permission denied: checkComponentPermission()

Comment: You should have the following permissions in the manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue when whitelisting your chromecast device.
Did you remember to check the box 'Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates' when you were setting up your chromecast device?

If not, please check it, reboot chromecast device and wait for a couple of hour.